# How to fix 'Can't open libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1'

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, ubuntu-19.04, msodbcsql17

In ubuntu 19.04 when working with Python3 in an anaconda environment with pyodbc 4.0.26 installed I get the `Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`!

Installed msodbcsql17 in ubuntu 19.04 like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). I tried all the suggestions from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/945) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/342). I did the analysis like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126811/ubuntu-18-04-and-msodbcsql17-cant-open-lib-should-i-file-a-bug-report/56235028#56235028).

With pyodbc 4.0.26, it is possible to check the driver in the anaconda environment with `python3 -c 'import pyodbc; print(pyodbc.drivers())'` and got `['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']`.

After the analysis and the solutions from the links shown above, I still am not able to get a connection to work with MS-SQL and Python3. Please help me!

Edit:

```
    ...:~$ ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
linux-vdso.so.1
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
```

Also:

```
    ~$ sudo locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2o-h20670df_0/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2p-h14c3975_0/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2p-h470a237_1/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

and:

```
    ~$ sudo locate libssl.so.1.0.0
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2o-h20670df_0/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2p-h14c3975_0/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2p-h470a237_1/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

And I am working in Anaconda environment.

Comment: libcrypto.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.1.0.0 are normally installed as part of the libssl1.0.0 package from the Ubuntu repositories. It looks like you have anaconda-specific copies of those libraries but they are not visible on the library path. You might try `sudo apt install libssl1.0.0` and see if that helps.

Comment: Installing libssl1.0.0 manually in Ubuntu 19.04 solves the problem, maybe with some other tuning I have done before - see the links mentioned in my question above.
You can install the old lib in ubuntu 19.04 with `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb` && `dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb`.
It will be installed parallel to libssl1.1.

Comment: @J.Gebsattel you should answer your own question with this comment, as it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Installing libssl1.0.0 manually in Ubuntu 19.04 solves the problem, maybe with some other tuning I have done before - see the links mentioned in my question above. You can install the old lib in ubuntu 19.04 with `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb`. It will be installed parallel to libssl1.1.

Comment: For debian 9+10 use this `wget http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2t-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libssl1.0.2_1.0.2t-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb` (found this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/945) and updated with correct link to deb file).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019-05-22 [Microsoft's installation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) have not been updated to include Ubuntu 19.04. Microsoft has added an entry for 19.04 in the repository, i.e.,

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/prod.list
```

but it may not be ready for prime-time. It certainly looks like they need to sort out the `libssl` dependency for 19.04 since `libssl1.0.0` is apparently no longer available

```
gord@VBox-Xubuntu1904:~$ sudo apt install libssl1.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```